# Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint and frameless flag makes don't keep my Qt window on bottom of all windows

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have an **undecorated window** that will stay **in the background of all windows**.

For this I apply two window flags to a this Qt window: `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and `Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint`.

If I apply only first flag it will undecorate my window. If I apply only the second flag I will have a window that is not undecorated but stays in the background of all windows.

I cannot understand why if I apply both flags I have two situations:

1. If the order is:

   ```
   view->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
   view->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
   ```

   I have a window that is undecoraded but doesn't stay on background.
2. If the order is:

   ```
   view->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
   view->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
   ```

   I have a window that is **NOT** undecoraded but **stays** on background.

How can I create a window that stays in background and is undecorated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing anything about Qt I guess what you might want is:

```
view->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
```

Flags are often just implemented as integers with certain bits set and `bitwise or` is used to set multiple bits of a flag.